# Django Rest Framework APIRequestFactory request object has no attribute 'query_params'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Lets say I have this APIView

```
class Dummy(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        return Response(data=request.query_params.get('uuid'))
```

To test it, I need to create a request object to pass into the `get` function

```
def test_dummy(self):
    from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory
    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    request = factory.get('/?uuid=abcd')
    DummyView().get(request)
```

It complains about `AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'query_params'`

Having a closer look, the factory creates a `WSGIRequest` instance instead of a DRF version `<class 'rest_framework.request.Request'>`.

```
>>> from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory
>>> factory = APIRequestFactory()
>>> request = factory.get('/')
>>> request.__class__
<class 'django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIRequest'>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's right. At the moment `APIRequestFactory` returns an `HttpRequest` object, which only get upgraded to a REST framework `Request` object once it gets to the view layer.

This mirrors the behavior that you'll see in an actual request, and what it *does* do is deal with eg. rendering JSON, XML or whatever other content type you have configured for your test requests.

However I agree that it's surprising behavior and at some point it will probably return a `Request` object, and the REST framework view will ensure that it only performs the `Request` upgrade on requests that instances of `HttpRequest`.

What you need to do in your case is *actually* call the view, rather than invoking the `.get()` method...

```
factory = APIRequestFactory()
request = factory.get('/?uuid=abcd')
view = DummyView.as_view()
response = view(request)  # Calling the view, not calling `.get()`
```

Comment: for me: I used a serializer inside a django class based view and got above mentioned exception. reasion: non-drf request was sent to serializer context/

Answer (score 20):

Refer to Tom's solution, `DummyView()(request)` will raise error:

```
TypeError: 'DummyView' object is not callable
```

Instead, should use `as_view` just like what you do in `urls.py`:

```
DummyView.as_view()(request)
```

DRF's `as_view` uses [method `initialize_request`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#initialize_requestself-request-42args-kwargs) to convert Django Request object to DRF version. You can try with:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
APIView().initialize_request(request)
>>> <rest_framework.request.Request object at 0xad9850c>
```

You can also use [APIClient](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#apiclient) to run test. It also tests URL dispatching.

```
from rest_framework.test import APIClient
client = APIClient()
client.post('/notes/', {'title': 'new idea'}, format='json')
```

Comment: While I accepted Tom's answer since it directly answers my question here, the `initialize_request` hint actually helps alot.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this answer is some time after the question was asked, but it solved this issue for me. Just override the `APIRequestFactory` class as below.

```
# Override APIRequestFactory to add the query_params attribute.
class MyAPIRequestFactory(APIRequestFactory):

    def generic(self, method, path, data='',
                content_type='application/octet-stream', secure=False,
                **extra):
        # Include the CONTENT_TYPE, regardless of whether or not data is empty.
        if content_type is not None:
            extra['CONTENT_TYPE'] = str(content_type)

        request = super(MyAPIRequestFactory, self).generic(
            method, path, data, content_type, secure, **extra)
        request.query_params = request.GET
        return request
```