# MultiValueDictKeyError when testing a GET endpoint using APIRequestFactory

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a `GET` endpoint that I am trying to test using the `APIRequestFactory`, following the method described in this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28429089

First off, I know this endpoint works because I get expected behavior when I send a `GET` request via cURL.

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -i -d "{\"cardinal_key\":12XXXX3, \"cardinal_type\":\"Npis\", \"terminal_type\":\"Deas\", \"candidate_count\":2}" http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/ranked_results/
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Mon, 28 Mar 2016 22:29:29 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.4.3
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Vary: Accept, Cookie
Content-Type: application/json

{"npi":"12XXXX3","first_name":"XXXXXX","middle_name":null,"last_name":"XXXXXX","full_name":"XXXXX, XXXX XXXXX","link_candidates":{"FXXXXX9":0.9900022451986468,"BXXXXXXX3":0.8483023431385707}}
```

However when I tried to make emulate this request using the factory, I got a `ValueError` exception (full trace below):

```python
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory
from linker.views import RankedResults
factory = APIRequestFactory()
options = {"cardinal_key":12XXXX3, "cardinal_type":"Npis", "terminal_type":"Deas", "candidate_count":2}
request = factory.get('/v1/ranked_results/', json.dumps(options), content_type='application/json')
view = RankedResults.as_view()
response = view(request)
```

`ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`

My next thought was that something was not working because I was trying to send the request as JSON, so I tried making the request without JSON and then I got a `MultiValueDictKeyError`:

```python
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory
from linker.views import RankedResults
factory = APIRequestFactory()
options = {"cardinal_key":12XXXX3, "cardinal_type":"Npis", "terminal_type":"Deas", "candidate_count":2}
request = factory.get('/v1/ranked_results/', options)
view = RankedResults.as_view()
response = view(request)
```

`MultiValueDictKeyError: "'cardinal_type'"`

My understanding of the `MultiValueDictKeyError` exception is that it happens when a key is not in the dictionary. Moreover, the documentation says that `MultiValueDict` is used for the case when you have multiple values with the same key -- I'm not sure why I'm seeing this because this is not the case with the request I'm trying to create.

I'm at a loss here - what am I missing?

view:

```python
class RankedResults(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        cardinal_instance = apps.get_model('warehouse', request.data['cardinal_type']).objects.get(reference_key=request.data['cardinal_key'])
        serializer = LinkModelSerializer(cardinal_instance, context=request.data)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializer:

```python
class LinkModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    link_candidates = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_candidate_links')

    def get_candidate_links(self, obj):
        terminal = apps.get_model('warehouse', self.context['terminal_type'])
        n = self.context['candidate_count']
        return dict(obj.top_n_candidates(terminal, n))

    class Meta:
        model = warehouse.Npis
        fields = ('npi', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'full_name', 'link_candidates')
        read_only_fields = ('link_candidates')
```

Trace for the case where I tried to send a JSON request:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-6b10ed2040c0> in <module>()
      2 factory = APIRequestFactory()
      3 options = {"cardinal_key":12XXXX3, "cardinal_type":"Npis", "terminal_type":"Deas", "candidate_count":2}
----> 4 request = factory.get('/v1/ranked_results/', json.dumps(options), content_type='application/json')
      5 view = RankedResults.as_view()
      6 response = view(request)

~/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py in get(self, path, data, **extra)
     79     def get(self, path, data=None, **extra):
     80         r = {
---> 81             'QUERY_STRING': urlencode(data or {}, doseq=True),
     82         }
     83         # Fix to support old behavior where you have the arguments in the url

~/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/http.py in urlencode(query, doseq)
     94         [(force_str(k),
     95          [force_str(i) for i in v] if isinstance(v, (list, tuple)) else force_str(v))
---> 96             for k, v in query],
     97         doseq)
     98 

~/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/http.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     94         [(force_str(k),
     95          [force_str(i) for i in v] if isinstance(v, (list, tuple)) else force_str(v))
---> 96             for k, v in query],
     97         doseq)
     98 

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

... lastly the trace for when I tried it without a JSON request:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py in __getitem__(self, key)
     82         try:
---> 83             list_ = super(MultiValueDict, self).__getitem__(key)
     84         except KeyError:

KeyError: 'cardinal_type'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MultiValueDictKeyError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-559ee170e692> in <module>()
      4 request = factory.get('/v1/ranked_results/', options)
      5 view = RankedResults.as_view()
----> 6 response = view(request)

~/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py in wrapped_view(*args, **kwargs)
     56     # function.
     57     def wrapped_view(*args, **kwargs):
---> 58         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
     59     wrapped_view.csrf_exempt = True
     60     return wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))(wrapped_view)

~/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py in view(request, *args, **kwargs)
     66             self.args = args
     67             self.kwargs = kwargs
---> 68             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
     69         view.view_class = cls
     70         view.view_initkwargs = initkwargs

~/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py in dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
    464 
    465         except Exception as exc:
--> 466             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
    467 
    468         self.response = self.finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)

~/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py in dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
    461                 handler = self.http_method_not_allowed
    462 
--> 463             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
    464 
    465         except Exception as exc:

~/views.py in get(self, request)
     36 class RankedResults(APIView):
     37     def get(self, request):
---> 38         cardinal_instance = apps.get_model('warehouse', request.data['cardinal_type']).objects.get(reference_key=request.data['cardinal_key'])
     39         serializer = LinkModelSerializer(cardinal_instance, context=request.data)
     40         return Response(serializer.data)

~/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py in __getitem__(self, key)
     83             list_ = super(MultiValueDict, self).__getitem__(key)
     84         except KeyError:
---> 85             raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
     86         try:
     87             return list_[-1]

MultiValueDictKeyError: "'cardinal_type'"
```

Comment: Could you also print `request.data` in `get` method using the first approach?

Comment: `---------------------------------------------------------------------------`
`AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)`
`<ipython-input-30-f17c4953e16d> in <module>()`
`----> 1 request.data`
    
`AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'`

Comment: However I can see the query string when I look at `request.__dict__` (this is an excerpt):

`'QUERY_STRING': 'cardinal_type=Npis&cardinal_key=1XXXXXX3&terminal_type=Deas&candidate_count=2',`

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [`request.data`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data):

> `request.data` returns the parsed content of the request body. This is similar to the standard `request.POST` and `request.FILES` attributes...

So, `request.data` is only available when you are passing something in the request body in a `POST`, `PUT` or `PATCH` request.

But you are making a `GET` request instead:

```
request = factory.get('/v1/ranked_results/', json.dumps(options), 
                      content_type='application/json')
```

For the `GET` request the correct way to get the query string is using [`request.query_params`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params):

> `request.query_params` is a more correctly named synonym for `request.GET`.
>
> For clarity inside your code, we recommend using `request.query_params` instead of the Django's standard `request.GET`. Doing so will help keep your codebase more correct and obvious - any HTTP method type may include query parameters, not just `GET` requests.

So, you shall be able to access what you want as following:

```
cardinal_type = request.query_params['cardinal_type']
# and similarly others
```

Comment: Thanks @AKS, I resolved this thanks to your comments, but I didn't do it exactly as you described. You are correct in that the `data` attribute is not available in a `GET` request, however the bit about using `query_params` didn't work. I used a `POST` request instead to send the query in the body of the request, and I was able to access the `data` attribute on `request`.

Comment: Could you tell me what was the problem when you used `GET` request with query params?