# APIRequestFactory with force_authenticate: GET returns a 404

Tags: python, unit-testing, get, django-rest-framework

I'm running an APITestCase using Rest Framework for Django and its APIRequestFactory.
I am able to return a status 200 when I request this api with APIClient, but I get a 404 with APIRequestFactory.  I'd like to use APIRequestFactory for it's "black box" effect in testing over APIClient.

I've modeled my test after the REST Framework docs for [force_authenticate](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#forcing-authentication).  It doesn't seem to be related to the issue of a APIRequestFactory returning an HTTPRequest instead of a Request as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421797/django-rest-framework-apirequestfactory-request-object-has-no-attribute-query-p).

Imports:

```
from rest_framework.test import APIClient, APITestCase, APIRequestFactory
from myapp.factories import UserFactory
from .views import internalPostListView
```

Test Using APIClient that successfully GET's (returns status 200):

```
class PostTests(APITestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.user = UserFactory()
        cls.client = APIClient()

    def test_successful_get_internal_post_list(self):
        self.user.is_superuser = True
        self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.user)
        response = self.client.get('/internal/posts/')

self.assertEquals(200, response.status_code)
```

Test using APIRequestFactory that can't find the api (returns status 404):

```
class PostTests(APITestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.factory = APIRequestFactory()
        cls.user = UserFactory()

    def test_successful_get_internal_post_list(self):

        self.user.is_superuser = True
        view = internalPostListView #Note: internalPostListView = InternalPostListView.as_view()
        request = self.factory.get('/internal/posts/')
        force_authenticate(request, user = self.user)
        response = view(request)

    self.assertEquals(200, response.status_code)
```

It's failing to GET the api, and is not an issue of authentication or permissions.  It seems to match the docs to me- what am I missing?